# writing files row wise to a text file in excel using python

Tags: python, excel

I have an excel file that goes like:

```
208324_at   akp13_human 7       6.9     5.8     5    7       5.7
208325_s_at akp13_human 25.5    21.3    9.9     9    13.1    8.5
```

I have to find the log of each value and write it to another text file. Following is the code:

```
    import xlrd
    from xlrd import open_workbook, XL_CELL_TEXT
    import math

    filename = "log_values.txt"
    computed_value = []
    i = 0

    with open_workbook("log10wholetest.xlsx") as f:
        sheet = f.sheet_by_index(0)
        n = sheet.nrows
        for i in range(0, n-1):
            a = sheet.row_values(i)
            b = map(float, a)

            for line in b :
                log = math.log10(float(line))
                computed_value.append(log)
                i += 1

            with open(filename, 'w') as g:
                for value in computed_value :
                    g.write("%s\t" % value)
```

This gives me a text file with results in a continuous line like:

```
2.55750720191   2.53995384166   2.21827285357
```

and so on.
But I want the results to be printed row wise, as in the log values of row2 of file should start from the second line( in the result file) and so on. 
I am sorry if this is an extremely simple question but I am totally new to python.

Comment: I am pretty sure your code is not formatted it as you intended.

Comment: ya.. I realized.. thanks

Comment: I'll answer when I am back atba computer, but basically you need to create a list per row, and append that list to your computer_value list.  Then you would iterate over each row of values so they are on separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a newline at the end of you g-while:

```
        with open(filename, 'w') as g:
            for value in computed_value :
                g.write("%s\t" % value)
            g.write('\n')
```

This will ensure that for each line in input, you get a single line in output `g`.

Comment: Hi.. thanks. I tried this but it is still giving me the output as continuous values.

Comment: On a second thought, it might be necessary to use `\r\n` when opening the file in Windows/Excel. Long story short, most systems except Windows use `\n` for newline, Windows uses `\r\n`.

Comment: Crud. Perhaps in the infinite wisdom of Microsoft, Excel in Mac also operates with `\r\n`? (I'm going on a limb here...)